# Is there a gallery of beamer outer themes available?

Tags: beamer

I want to see and compare all the [beamer outer themes](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/tree/main/base/themes/outer). Something like [this](https://hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/).

Is this available somewhere?

I know I can generate examples myself, but I prefer to use something already available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find a list, including images, of all the outer themes which ship with beamer, in section `16.2 Outer Themes` of the [beamer user guide](https://texdoc.org/serve/beamer/0).

Here a short overview with just the images without all the documentation between them:

[image]

Note to self:

The code for the image

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=1pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
\ttfamily

\foreach \macro in {default,infolines,miniframes,shadow,sidebar,smoothbars,smoothtree,split,tree}{

  \macro
  
  \includegraphics[width=5cm,page=1]{beamerugoutertheme\macro}
  \includegraphics[width=5cm,page=2]{beamerugoutertheme\macro}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! What's the difference between `smoothbars` and `miniframes`?

Comment: @HappyFace The difference is the transition between the coloured bars. If you try them out you'll see that in smoothbars there is colour gradient between the elements, in miniframes it is a sharp transition